# Retropie USB Gamepad not configured

Tags: retropie, emulation

I've set up RetroPie in Raspbian Jessie and am able to start it up. I have a SNES controller and configured it on the first start up. It works perfectly fine in the menu, but when I select a rom, I get a pop up that says USB Gamepad not configured. I'm using version 3.6 of RetroPie. I tried following this link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhkEnDdygbQ      (useful part is at 5:40)

but my `opt/retropie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg` file is empty so I'm not sure what to do to make my controller work in games.

Comment: Hi, did you checked https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/First-Installation ?

Comment: I did. I ended up grabbing a new micro sd and directly putting the retropie-3.6-rpi2_rpi3 image on there and was able to play the games.

Comment: So, problem is solved already, right ?

Comment: Yes. Instead of trying to run emulationstation through a Jessie image, I just loaded a retropie image to my sd card